# Should I accept to do psychometric tests while employed, in US and UK?

Tags: human-resources, psychology

I have been asked to do a psychometric test "as part of my business skills training" but I am afraid it might be used against me at some point.

Is it legal, in the US and in the UK respectively, to make employees undergo psychometric tests?

Comment: "One part of the field is concerned with the objective measurement of skills and knowledge, abilities, attitudes, personality traits, and educational achievement." Seems to be all work related. Stuff they will figure out anyone in due time anyway. I do however not know if it is common, nor do I know if you should accept.

Comment: Seems like double edged, either a tool to get something against you, or either something that if you pass well could lead to a promotion, but we can't read minds. To answer to your question some more details would be welcome, Who are pushing those tests (HR ?) ? Is there only you to your knowledge ? Do you know if your comanager is somewhat jealous of your success ?

Comment: Whether you trust your company is something only you can decide and whether this is common or not is a tricky question, doesn't usually make for a good question on this site, and ultimately doesn't really help you decide either way. This kind of testing happens, though more often in hiring, and there are fierce proponents and detractors of the concept. I'm not sure your specific concerns over their use of this information are valid though so I'm not really sure your question can be answered in its present form.

Comment: edited question, focus on this being actually allowed by law.

Comment: I edited the question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it legal, in the US and in the UK respectively

***Yes, it is legal*** because all they're doing in giving you a test to complete to see how you fare against certain areas of working styles and what type of problem solving you're good at.

It's not illegal to test employees like this, at least not in the UK. As for the US, I don't know but the employer must adhere to UK law if operating in the UK, so whether it is or not is irrelevant in this case, but I'd confidently bet it's still not illegal.

It's also **not illegal to drug test you** either, but there are some rules in UK law about this which you can [read on the Gov.UK site](https://www.gov.uk/monitoring-work-workers-rights/drug-testing), essentially, it states...

> - limit testing to employees that need to be tested
> - ensure the tests are random
> - not single out particular employees for testing unless this is justified by the nature of their jobs

As for your (*technically first*) other question...

> I am afraid it might be used against me at some point

It may well be. But ***I guarantee you that if you refuse to do the test, it'll come off a lot worse for you than if you just do the test***. They may use it against you but you may also find they use it to provide you with support to better your abilities and make your job easier and better.

Only you know what the company you work for is like and how it operates. Usually these tests are used for improving the team as a whole and to help people who may be obviously struggling in a certain area. You might ace it as well in which case it doesn't even matter.

Comment: A test has to bear a clear relationship to the job at issue. Various psychological and personality tests, cognitive tests, fitness and health tests and others require attention, and, if really poorly prepared, may be questioned for legality. See [here](http://employment.findlaw.com/workplace-privacy/tests-at-work-your-rights.html) for instance. May not be the best source but the author does not provide any.